# Is it possible to define a sign with no text in Vim

Tags: vim, sign

I'd love to be able to just change the color of a line's sign without any text in it.  Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by `line's sign`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim doesn't like plain spaces for the `:sign text=` argument, but I've managed to define a sign with a text of two no-breaking spaces (U+00A0):

```
execute "sign define foo text=\<Char-0xa0>\<Char-0xa0> texthl=WarningMsg"
sign place 42 name=foo line=42 buffer=1
```

Comment: Awesome!  I keep looking for a way to try non-breaking spaces, but never quite got the right syntax.  This does the trick perfectly!